# Tesseract - preserve worker

Tags: javascript, ocr

I have a javascript app that reads invoices.  It's working perfectly but I would like to improve it's performance a bit.

The way the app works is this.  There are Next and Submit buttons.  After either, a new image is loaded and a function doOcr is called.  In each instance of doOCR, a worker is created which must take time.  I am trying to figure out how to move the worker outside the function so it doesn't need to be created each time.  Code is below.  Thoughts?

```
//ocr the image and fill values
function doOCR(){(async () => {
        worker = Tesseract.createWorker();
        await worker.load();
        await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
        await worker.initialize('eng');             
        const values = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
              const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(imgFile, { rectangle: rectangles[i] });
        values.push(text);
        }
        console.log(values);

        //calculate and display result 
        dir = values[0].split(' ');
        $("#inDir").val(dir[1]);
        //get invoice number
        $("#inVendor").val(dir[0]);
        //get invoice #
        var str = values[0]; 
        var n = str.indexOf("Invoice:", 0);
        var n1 = str.indexOf("Invoice", n+5);
        invoice = str.substr(n+9, n1-n-9);
        $("#inInvoice").val(invoice);

        await worker.terminate();

        $('#status').attr('src','check.png').show();

})()};
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think I got it by changing the top half of the function to:

```js
function doOCR(){(async () => {
    if (typeof(worker) == "undefined") {
        worker = Tesseract.createWorker();
        await worker.load();
        await worker.loadLanguage('eng');
        await worker.initialize('eng');     
    }           
    
    const values = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < rectangles.length; i++) {
        const { data: { text } } = await worker.recognize(imgFile, {rectangle: rectangles[i]});
        values.push(text);
    }
    console.log(values);

    [ ... ]
```

and removed

```
await worker.terminate();
```